# Difference among return view(), return response()->view() and abort() in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Suppose i want to return 404 error view from my controller's method and i have this block of code.

```
try {

        file_get_contents('http://www.somewebsite.com');

    } 
catch (\Exception $e) {

        return view('errors.404'); // View::make('errors.404');

        // or                       

        return response()->view('errors.404'); // Response::view('errors.404');

        // or

        abort(404); // App::abort(404);

    }
```

Each time i'll see the same view output of 404. Here is my questions.

***What is the difference among view(), response()->view() and abort()?***

***What is the particular use cases of them?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`view()` is just a shorthand for `response()->view()`

`response()->view()` returns the specified view with the status code 200, but you are able to modify the response in many ways. For example set other headers or another status code like 301.

`abort()` throws an NotFoundHttpException or HttpException and will make Laravel look for a view named like the corresponding code in `views/errors` so you don't have to specify the view on your own.

Comment: But all those returning same output. Why shouldn't i use view() all the time?

Comment: @Prs Because of the status code that is sent to the browser for the error page. Not essential for the user but for search engines. You don't have to use `abort()` but you _should_.

Comment: view() is not a shorthand for response()->view() 

view()'s function signature is view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
response()->view()'s function signature is view($view,$data = [],$status = 200,array $headers = [])

Comment: @NobodyImportant already mentioned it, but unless this was the case back in 2016, view() does not return the same as response()->view() (..\View\View vs. ..\Http\Response). I don't think this question has been properly answered.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting since I've found little explicit info on this. Other answers have pointed out what `abort()` does, but still, what about `view()` vs. `response()->view()`?

**The `view()` helper function** (signature `view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])`) returns a `\Illuminate\Contracts\View\View` (or a `\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory` if no arguments are passed to it).

**The `response()->view()` method** (signature `view($view, $data = [], $status = 200, array $headers = [])`) returns a `\Illuminate\Http\Response`

From https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/responses#other-response-types:

> If you need control over the response's status and headers but also need to return a view as the response's content, you should use the view method:

```
return response()
            ->view('hello', $data, 200)
            ->header('Content-Type', $type);
```

**The best I can understand, the `response()` methods give you more control over the response**, such as a custom status and headers (as in the above example). Personally, I would use the `view()` helper for most of my controller method returns, then use `response()->view()` when I might need to customize the http response. When using method return types, if I'm not sure what the return might be in the future, `Illuminate\Http\Response` might be best:

```
public function index(Request $request):Illuminate\Http\Response
{
    ...
    return response()->[whatever]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use view() or response()->view() the HTTP response code your client recieves will be 200 aka OK. When using abort(404) the code will be 404 NOT FOUND!